# Make glyphicon hover when cursor over text

Tags: php, html, css, hover, glyphicons

How can i make only the glyphicon to hover when i put my cursor over the text? Right now it hovers only when i put my cursor over the glyphicon but when i put my cursor over the text it does nothing.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active" ><span class="button hvr-pop glyphicon glyphicon-home" > </span>AVALEHT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about "><span class="button hvr-pop glyphicon glyphicon-heart" > </span>MINU TÖÖD </a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><span class="button hvr-pop glyphicon glyphicon-user" > </span>MINUST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><span class="button hvr-pop glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" > </span>KONTAKT</a></li>
</ul>

.navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover + .hvr.pop{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to open hover.css and copied everything containing hvr-pop to

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover .hvr-pop{ 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
         display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pop;
  animation-name: hvr-pop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the class correctly... just change

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover .hvr-pop
```

Comment: I got closer to the result i want to get to with this. But the effect doesn't start working on the glyphicons. 
.navbar-nav li a:hover .hvr-pop{
     display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color:black;
   
}
Only color:black; works.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make it as follow;

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" class="box">1</div>
<div id="b" class="box">2</div>
<div id="c" class="box">3</div>
<div id="d" class="box">4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#aaa;
  display: inline-block;
}
#a:hover ~ #c {
    background: red;
}
```

And you can find live example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tanbi/6a48v9be/)